# Using Arduino Motor Shield

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-motor-shield, home-automation

I'm looking to create a blind controller and have set up the hardware and software as I think it should be.

I had the software working fine using an IC motor driver, but as I am no great at soldering, I decided to use a motor shield. The software (below) now only turns the motor one way. I did amend the code to try to get the motor to turn the other way, and it did but only when the 'BlindOn' was during it's on.

Therefore, the hardware is set up correctly (pins D1 and D3) but there is some modification needed to this program; any help or advice greatly appreciated.

```
/**********************************************************************************
  * Code for controlling multiple devices connected to one NodeMCU using Amazon Echo
  * 
  * Written by Sid for Sid's E Classroom
  * 
  * https://www.youtube.com/c/SidsEClassroom
  *********************************************************************************/
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "fauxmoESP.h"

#define WIFI_SSID "VM0718169" //change your Wifi name
#define WIFI_PASS "8kcgvwSFymjx" //Change your Wifi Password
#define SERIAL_BAUDRATE                 115200

fauxmoESP fauxmo;
//declare switching pins
//Change pins according to your NodeMCU pinouts
#define BlindOp D1
#define BlindCl D3
#define Test D2

volatile bool BlindOpOn = false;  // needs to be volatile since used in ISR
volatile bool BlindClOn = false;
volatile bool TestOn = false;

const unsigned long BlindOpOnTime = 5;    // seconds
const unsigned long BlindClOnTime = 5;     // seconds
const unsigned long TestOnTime = 5;

volatile unsigned long BlindOpStartTime;
volatile unsigned long BlindClStartTime;
volatile unsigned long TestStartTime;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Wifi Setup
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void wifiSetup() {

    // Set WIFI module to STA mode
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

    // Connect
    Serial.printf("[WIFI] Connecting to %s ", WIFI_SSID);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);

    // Wait
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.println();

    // Connected!
    Serial.printf("[WIFI] STATION Mode, SSID: %s, IP address: %s\n", WiFi.SSID().c_str(), WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Device Callback
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void callback(uint8_t device_id, const char * device_name, bool state) {
  Serial.print("Device "); Serial.print(device_name); 
  Serial.print(" state: ");
  if (state) {
    Serial.println("ON");
  } else {
    Serial.println("OFF");
  }
  //Switching action on detection of device name
  if ( (strcmp(device_name, "BlindOp") == 0) ) {
    // adjust the relay immediately!
    if (state) {
      digitalWrite(BlindOp, HIGH);
      BlindOpOn = true;
      BlindOpStartTime = millis();
    } else {
      digitalWrite(BlindOp, LOW);
      BlindOpOn = false;
    }
  }
  if ( (strcmp(device_name, "BlindCl") == 0) ) {
    // adjust the relay immediately!
    if (state) {
      digitalWrite(BlindCl, HIGH);
      BlindClOn = true;
      BlindClStartTime = millis();
    } else {
      digitalWrite(BlindCl, LOW);
      BlindClOn = false;
    }
  }
  if ( (strcmp(device_name, "Test") == 0) ) {
    // adjust the relay immediately!
    if (state) {
      digitalWrite(Test, HIGH);
      TestOn = true;
      TestStartTime = millis();
    } else {
      digitalWrite(Test, LOW);
      TestOn = false;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
    //Initialize pins to Low on device start
    pinMode(BlindOp, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(BlindOp, LOW);
    pinMode(BlindCl, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(BlindCl, LOW);
    pinMode(Test, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(Test, LOW);

    // Init serial port and clean garbage
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUDRATE);
    Serial.println("FauxMo demo sketch");
    Serial.println("After connection, ask Alexa/Echo to 'turn <devicename> on' or 'off'");

    // Wifi
    wifiSetup();

    // Device Names for Simulated Wemo switches
    fauxmo.addDevice("BlindOp");
    fauxmo.addDevice("BlindCl");
    fauxmo.addDevice("Test");
    fauxmo.onMessage(callback);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long duration;

  fauxmo.handle();
  if ( BlindOpOn == true ) {
    duration = (millis() - BlindOpStartTime) / 1100;  // convert to seconds
    if ( duration >= BlindOpOnTime ) {
      digitalWrite(BlindOp, LOW);
      BlindOpOn = false;
    }
  }

  if ( BlindClOn == true ) {
    duration = (millis() - BlindClStartTime) / 1100;  // convert to seconds
    if ( duration >= BlindClOnTime ) {
      digitalWrite(BlindCl, LOW);
      BlindClOn = false;
    }
  }
  if ( TestOn == true ) {
    duration = (millis() - TestStartTime) / 1100;  // convert to seconds
    if ( duration >= TestOnTime ) {
      digitalWrite(Test, LOW);
      TestOn = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `if ( BlindClOn == true )` - this strange convention is inexplicably popular in Arduino-related code...

Comment: you are using inconsistent programming style .... at one point you use `if (state)` and  at another point you use the redundant `if ( BlindOpOn == true )` ..... the first style is the desirable one to use .....  use `if ( BlindOpOn )` for the second one ...... the `if ( BlindOpOn == true )` is redundant because it means `if ( true == true )` when `BlindOpOn` is true

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I think the mismatch is due to various people editing the original, but this does work when using an IC motor driver...it will only opens when using the shield, and won't close.

Ideally, it would be one device which operates for a set time when turned on to open, and operates for a fixed time to close.

I need to learn more as I find the many }s used confusing, I've not much experience in programming in general